# Create bulk topics & subscribers in google cloud

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am looking for a procedure to create bulk topics and subscribers using script or program. I have all topics&subscribers create commands in script.

How to execute the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generally 3 ways of interacting with Google Cloud Platform.

1. The web UI (http://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Use the API directly (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/apis)
3. Using the Cloud SDK command line tools, especially `gcloud` (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/)

The web UI is generally unsuitable for bulk/automated actions, but the latter two would work well. Using the API depends on the language you prefer, so I'll give an example using `gcloud` and `bash` (assuming you've already installed and configured `gcloud`):

```
$ head -n 2 topics.txt
topic-1
topic-2
$ while read topic; do gcloud pubsub topics create $topic; done < topics.txt
```

Subscriptions is slightly trickier, since `gcloud pubsub subscriptions create` needs a `--topic` flag as well as a positional argument for the name of the subscription, but the idea is pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks Zachary for your comments. I would use APIs to interact with cloud using Java lang. Any instructions on Java APIs ?